# jQuery Validate function fires on every page regardless of whether form exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm currently using the jQuery validate plugin to validate the forms used within my site. However, there are multiple form possibilities and I am using a one size fits all validation script that is supposed to target all forms within a div that has a certain class.

Currently my validation is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
        isemail: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
      });

      jQuery.validator.addMethod("ContainsAtLeastOneDigit", function (value) { return /[a-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-z]/i.test(value); }, 'Your password must contain at least 1 number');

      $(".icams_inserted form").validate({
        errorClass : "invalid",
        validClass : "valid",
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
           var err = this.numberOfInvalids();
           if (err > 1) {
             var word = "errors";
             var field = "fields";
             $("#error_message").html("The form contains " + this.numberOfInvalids() +" "+ word + ". Please correct the highlighted " + field + " below."); this.defaultShowErrors();
             }else{
                var word = "error";
                var field ="field";
                if (err < 1) {
                   $("#error_message").html("");
                   this.defaultShowErrors();
                }else{
                   $("#error_message").html("The form contains " + this.numberOfInvalids() +" "+ word + ". Please correct the highlighted " + field + " below."); this.defaultShowErrors();
                }
             }
       },
       submitHandler: function(form){           
            /*For the registration form, move the email address the user has entered into the hidden email field*/
            if (form.hasClass('prefs')) {
                var mail = $('#p_username').val();
                $('input[type="hidden"][name="p_email_address"]').val(mail);
            }
            form.submit();
       },
       rules : {
           p_password:{
               minlength: 8,
               ContainsAtLeastOneDigit: true
           },
           p_password_conf:{
               equalTo: p_password,
               minlength: 8,
               ContainsAtLeastOneDigit: true
           }
       },
       messages:{
          p_password_conf:{
              equalTo: 'The passwords entered do not match'
          }
       }
    });
  })
```

However, for some reason the validation seems to kick in on every page, even pages that do not have any forms. This then produces the following error in Firebug:

```
   ReferenceError: p_password is not defined
   equalTo: p_password,
```

Does anyone know why this is? My understanding was that the plugin should only fire on elements that are targeted by it in this case forms inclosed within an element with the class of .icams_inserted but this does not appear to be the case. It was also my understanding the the validation should only take place if the element in question is found. In this case there is not element on the page with a name of p_password so the validation script should not fire. I'm really at a loss as to why this is doing this.

I have even tried using dummy classes that do not exist in my whole site and it still seems that the validation is firing regardless. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML markup that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised:**

Your error...

```
ReferenceError: p_password is not defined
equalTo: p_password,
```

<s>...as spelled out above, is being caused by your incorrect rule declaration...</s>

```
equalTo: p_password // <-- missing quotes
```

Must be like this...

```
equalTo: "#p_password" // <-- targeted by id in this example
```

[As per docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/), the `equalTo` value is the "selector" of the other field and it's surrounded by quotes.

EDIT:  Through jsFiddle, I was able to see `equalTo` rule working even without quotes around the value.

As the page loads, the code within the `.validate()` call is being parsed and error is being triggered whenever the `p_password` field does not exist.  "validation" is not firing.

---

---

Original follows:

---

**Quote Question Title**:

> *"jQuery Validate function fires on every page regardless of whether form exists"*

"Validation" is not firing.  The `.validate()` call is the *initialization* method of the plugin.

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"validation seems to kick in on every page, even pages that do not have any forms."*

"Validation" does not kick in unless there is an event triggered by the attached form.  When you simply attach `.validate()` to a form, you are only initializing the plugin on that form.

`$('#myform').validate()` ≠ "validation"

However,

`$('#myform').validate()` = *initialization* of the validation plugin on the form with `id="myform"`

---

**Quote OP's Comment**:

> *"Wrong. The documentation clearly states here that calling validate in this way should only validate the form specified."*

Yes, "validation" will only occur on the specified form.   However, calling `.validate()` is **not** the same as *"validation kicking in"*.  Calling the `.validate()` method is only what *initializes* the Validation plugin.

The "validation" will only be triggered by one of the events captured by the plugin, such as "key up", "on blur", or "on click of the submit button".  "Validation" will **not** occur by simply loading the page... unless you programmatically trigger it through a *testing* method, such as `.valid()`.

Comment: Wrong. The documentation clearly states here that calling validate in this way should only validate the form specified. http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: @jezzpin,  and there is no form on your page! How do you expect to initialize the plugin on a form that does not exist?

Comment: How do you know what my page looks like? I haven't even put a link. My form is within the .icams_inserted div. I am targeting the form element directly meaning any forms in this div will be validated.

Comment: @jezzipin quote:  _"validation seems to kick in on every page, **even pages that do not have any forms.**"_

Comment: Javascript will complain about `p_password` regardless of whether anything with your class exists.  This is just basic parsing in the browser, nothing to do with Validate.

Comment: p_password refers to the name of the element that is being targeted. Not the id.

Comment: @jezzipin, fair enough.

Comment: @jezzipin, regardless, you're getting this error because you're referencing something (`p_password`) that doesn't exist.